# Worker Role third-party software

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-storage, azure-web-roles, azure-blob-storage

We have third-party software hosted in Azure Virtual Machines.  This software hosts a service which is consumed by one of our Cloud Service Web Roles.

The issue is that the network latency between the VM and the Web Role is significantly affecting the performance of our application.

**A solution would be to publish this third-party software in the same Cloud Service (in a Worker Role)**.

**VM Role** sounds like a [good implementation for the above problem](https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/platform-as-a-service/installing-third-party-software-on-windows-azure-%E2%80%93-what-are-the-options/).  Unfortunately this is a deprecated service!

One idea would be to package the relevant installation scripts and files into a Visual Studio project and configure the ServiceDefinition to set up the software accordingly. The concern here is that the installation files are over 1Gb.

Is there currently any Azure service that can support my problem?  Is there a replacement to the VM Role?

Comment: Just curious, regarding latency: Are your Virtual Machines in the same region as your Cloud Services? And if so, are you direct-connecting (e.g. virtual network) or are you routing back out through Azure's load-balancer to xzy.cloudapp.net (which could add a bit of latency)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though a bit old, but you may want to take a look at [`Azure Bootstraper`](https://bootstrap.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex. From the project description page:

> The Windows Azure Bootstrapper is a command line tool meant to be used
>   by your running Web and Worker roles in Windows Azure.  This tool
>   allows you to easily download resources (either public resources or
>   ones in your blob storage), extract them if necessary, and launch
>   them.  Since you don't want to always download and run during
>   restarts, it will also help track those dependencies and only launch
>   an installer one time!  In addition, there are some very useful
>   features that make it a great tool to package with your roles.

Yet another idea (though I have not tried it) would be to make use of `Azure File Service`. What you could do is upload the installers in an Azure File Service share and then mount the share in your Cloud Service VMs and use it as a drive on your VM. You should be able to install software that way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately Azure File Service is also still in preview. The bootstrap looks interesting, but you raise a good point - it's a bit outdated. Perhaps we could use BLOB storage instead?  I think the transfer rate between the worker role and blob should be quick enough.

Comment: Even though Azure File Service is still in preview, I would still go with it and give it a try. Blob storage would be my fallback option. Azure Bootstrapper makes use of Blob Storage if I am not mistaken. Even though it is an old product but the thing is that basics of Azure Blob Storage (e.g. downloading file from blob storage) has not changed so that should not impact you IMO. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that bundling 3rd-party software inside the cspkg can be problematic, size-wise.

It's common practice to download needed software from either a startup command file (.cmd) or from `OnStart()`. These downloads can be sourced from anywhere that you have access to: Azure blob storage, the actual vendors themselves (e.g. download from their public download link), etc. In your startup script, you'd need to handle the downloading (and potential unzipping) into a local folder, then installing as necessary.